# Send file from Server to Client on Linux in C

Tags: c, linux, file, sockets, send

I have a problem with this code. The problem is that I have to develop a client-server model with this futures:

1. Client type: "GETfile_name.txt";
2. Server receives the request and send file's size;
3. Server send the file;

The problem is that Server doesn't send the file to the client. Thanks to all for your help.

The code is this:

#### Server:

```
f = fopen(file_name,"r");

/* file's size */
fseek(f,0L,SEEK_END);
size = ftell(f);
fseek(f,0L,SEEK_SET);

/* convert int to string */
sprintf(file_size,"%d",size); 

/* send file's size to the client */
Send(s,file_size,sizeof(file_size)); 

/* send file to the client */
buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*size);  
bzero(buffer,sizeof(char)*size);
x = fread(binoltro,sizeof(char),sizeof(char)*dimensione,f);
Send(s,binoltro,x);
```

#### Client:

```
/* wait file's size */
recv(s,buffer,MAX,0); 
printf("Remote server will send: %s Bytes\n",buffer);
size = atoi(buffer);

/* execute malloc */
buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
bzero(buffer,size*sizeof(char));

Recv(s,buffer,size*sizeof(char));
fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char),size*sizeof(char),f);
printf("File: %s",buffer);

/* clean the buffer */
bzero(buffer,MAX);

/* do free */
free(buffer);
fclose(f);
```

With:

```
int Recv (int s, char *ptr, size_t maxlen){
size_t n;
ssize_t nread;
char c;

for (n=1; n<maxlen; n++)
{
    nread=recv(s, &c, 1, 0);
    if (nread == 1)
    {
        *ptr++ = c;
        if (c == '\n')
            break;
    }
    else if (nread == 0)    
    {
        *ptr = 0;
        return (n-1); 
    }
    else
        return (-1); 
}
*ptr = 0;
return (n);
}
```

And:

```
int Send(int s, char *ptr, size_t nbytes){
size_t  nleft;
ssize_t nwritten;

for (nleft=nbytes; nleft > 0; )
{
    nwritten = send(s, ptr, nleft, 0);
    if (nwritten <=0)
        return (nwritten);
    else
    {
        nleft -= nwritten;
        ptr += nwritten;
    }
}
return (nbytes - nleft); 
}
```

Comment: If the message is too long to pass atomically through the underlying protocol, the error EMSGSIZE is returned, and the message is not transmitted.  Do You get this return value? You might need to not send the whole file at once, but in chunks (since send can't send whatever size you want normally).

Comment: I don't have check the error EMSGSIZE because I am new with C language. But I have try with a small file such us "football is good" but nothing. The Client doesn't receive nothing

Comment: check the return values and get back to us before you get downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: the return value of errno?

Comment: It seems like you haven't done any diagnosis on your own. Poke at your program with a debugger to see if the values of the various variables are what you believe they should be and check all `errno`s first.

Comment: The problem is that it seems to be all correct because doesn't have any errno value from the methods used. If after:                       x = fread(binoltro,sizeof(char),sizeof(char)*dimensione,f); I write: printf("%s",binoltro); all the file appears to the standard output of the server. So, it seems that the Send doesn't work

Comment: Don't use the sizeof(filesize) when sending the file's size use strlen(filesize) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that your Recv() function breaks when either it receives a '\n' or there is no more data or maxlen is reached. None of these conditions match after your client received the last byte of the file length so it reads on and the file data is lost.

I would suggest you fill the file length to a fixed number of digits( e.g. 10)  by using

```
sprintf( file_size, "%010s", size );
```

and use a modified Recv() function like this:

```
int Recv (int s, char *ptr, size_t nbytes ){
    size_t n;
    ssize_t nread;


    while( nbytes > 0 ) {
        if( (nread = recv( s, ptr, nbytes, 0 )) <= 0 )
            return -1; /* Error */

        ptr += nread;
        nbytes -= nread;
    }
    +ptr = '\0';
    return 0; /* OK */
}
```

Then your client can first read the file size using

```
Recv( s, buffer, 10 )
```

and then the data using

```
Recv( s, ..., atoi( buffer ) )
```

Make sure to alloc file size + 1 because of the '\0' that is added by Recv()

Comment: any output from client and / or server ?

Comment: Exactly. Server's buffer contains all the file. But it seems that the Send doesn't send any byte. I don't understand why. Really.

Comment: Do you mean you don't even get the file size? Is it stuck in recv() or what does recv() return (return value + errno). What does each send return (return value + errno)?

Comment: one more thing I haven't seen before: I you try what I've suggested, please change `sizeof(file_size)` to `strlen(file_size)` in the first Send() (if file_size is char *, then sizeof() returns 4 or 8 which is too small, otherwise it returns the array length which is at least one byte too big). But don't forget to log the results of all send() and recv() calls.

Comment: With the Client's recv I obtain this value of errno: ERROR: Undefined error: 0 (with 0 = errno)

Comment: Done (change sizeof with strlen)! But nothing it doesn't work!

Comment: OK, is it the first recv() you're talking about? What's the value of nread? What to the send() call return? Maybe you could add a complete log to your question.